# usage of unknown function 'SHORTEST_PATH()'

Tags: arangodb

I'm really new to arangodb (and graph databases). I'm trying to use the sortest_path function:

```
FOR p in SHORTEST_PATH(imdb_vertices, imdb_edges, "imdb_vertices/349","imdb_vertices/1931", "any", { paths: true})
RETURN p
```

But the shells returns:

```
usage of unknown function 'SHORTEST_PATH()'
```

In the docs I can't find a working example of use of this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the SHORTEST_PATH function has been added in ArangoDB 1.4.11. Can you make sure you are using an ArangoDB server version as least as high as that?

Second, a few examples for SHORTEST_PATH should be here:
https://www.arangodb.org/manuals/1/Aql.html#AqlFunctionsGraph

Comment: I have version 2.0.0 installed. Is the function available in 2.0?

Comment: Ah! I was trying in a 1.4.8 server instead of another one that has the 2.0 vers. Sorry for the noise. (yes, I need the weekend :) )

Comment: To confirm: SHORTEST_PATH is available in 2.0, too.

Comment: 2.0 has all features of 1.4.8 plus Sharding.